# Wordpress API, new post with categories and tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple script in node, but the problem is with API in general.

I can easily create a new post through the API, but I can't add categories or tags to it.

My code:

```
 client.newPost({
    title: 'title of the post',
    status: 'publish',
    type: 'post',
    content: 'content of the post',
    categories: ["category1", "category2"] 
}, function(err, id) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else console.log(id)
});
```

I pasted only the interesting part, as the rest works great.
Let's even say those categories exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the wordpress codebase, I found the solution for this question.

As I said this api is for node-wordpress, but it may help other apis as I didn't find the answer anywhere else.

You simply use this

```
wordpress.newPost({
    title: title,
    status: 'publish',
    type: 'post',
    content: content,
    terms: {
        category: [2],
        post_tag: [3]

    },
    tags: 'bling'


}, function(err, id) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else console.log(id)
});
```

As you can see you have "terms"
and inside it, you have "category" and "post_tag".

Currently you can only pass ids, and they should exist in the wordpress destination otherwise it will fail.